# Quickbooks Php SDK - CheckNullResponseAndThrowException - Response Null or Empty

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks

Please kindly assist me on below error:
2015-04-16 10:45:10 - D:\projects\QuickBooksv3-php-sdk-2.0.5\DataService\DataService.php - 340 - CheckNullResponseAndThrowException - Response Null or Empty

3 days ago, I had successfully test quickbooks php sdk. 
But today when I going to integrate with system, it hit error. 
The code is same as 3 days ago.

Here is my code:

```
//Create new invoice
$invoiceObj2 = new IPPInvoice();
$invoiceObj2->DocNumber="1025";

//Add customer
$customerRef2= new IPPReferenceType();
$customerRef2->value= "1";
$invoiceObj2->CustomerRef= $customerRef2;

//Create Line
$line2 = new IPPLine();
$line2->Amount= 1*90.84;

$linetype2= new IPPLineDetailTypeEnum();
$linetype2->value="SalesItemLineDetail";

$lineDetail2 = new IPPSalesItemLineDetail();
$lineDetail2->ItemRef = "4";
$lineDetail2->UnitPrice = 90.84;
$lineDetail2->Qty= 1;

$line2->DetailType=$linetype2;
$line2->SalesItemLineDetail=$lineDetail2;

$invoiceObj2->Line=$line2;

$resultingInvoiceObj2 = $dataService->Add($invoiceObj2);

echo "Created Invoice Id={$resultingInvoiceObj2->Id}. Reconstructed response body:<br/><br/>";
$xmlBody = XmlObjectSerializer::getPostXmlFromArbitraryEntity($resultingInvoiceObj2, $urlResource);
echo "<pre>";
echo $xmlBody . "<br/>";
echo "</pre>";
```

Please kindly help to point out my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please change the base url for using sandbox QBO account or use production tokens for connecting to existing QBO accounts.
Your issue might be related to this change-https://developer.intuit.com/v2/blog/2014/10/24/intuit-developer-now-offers-quickbooks-sandboxes

You can also try changing the values and then try integrating into QB

Answer (score 0):

I have solved same problem checking required params. Please check required fields.

Required fields are at least:

```
DocNumber
TxnDate
CustomerRef
```

at least one Line record

```
Line.DetailType
Line.Amount
Line.Description
```

at least one `Line.SalesItemLineDetail`

```
Line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef
Line.SalesItemLineDetail.Quantity
Line.SalesItemLineDetail.UnitPrice
```

I have modified your code and run. Its working

Final modified  code:

```
//Create new invoice
$invoiceObj2 = new IPPInvoice();
$invoiceObj2->DocNumber="1025";
$invoiceObj2->TxnDate = "2016-10-19";

//Add customer
$customerRef2= new IPPReferenceType();
$customerRef2->value= "1";
$invoiceObj2->CustomerRef= $customerRef2;

//Create Line
$line2 = new IPPLine();
$line2->Amount= 1*90.84;
$Line2->Description = 'Test Product';

$linetype2= new IPPLineDetailTypeEnum();
$linetype2->value="SalesItemLineDetail";

$lineDetail2 = new IPPSalesItemLineDetail();
$lineDetail2->ItemRef = "4";
$lineDetail2->UnitPrice = 90.84;
$lineDetail2->Qty= 1;

$line2->DetailType=$linetype2;
$line2->SalesItemLineDetail=$lineDetail2;

$invoiceObj2->Line=$line2;

$resultingInvoiceObj2 = $dataService->Add($invoiceObj2);

echo "Created Invoice Id={$resultingInvoiceObj2->Id}. Reconstructed response body:<br/><br/>";
$xmlBody = XmlObjectSerializer::getPostXmlFromArbitraryEntity($resultingInvoiceObj2, $urlResource);
echo "<pre>";
echo $xmlBody . "<br/>";
echo "</pre>";
```